# error: field has incomplete type

Tags: c, struct

I am attempting to port a library to Mac OS X. The compiler is reporting an incomplete type error. Specifically: field has incomplete type 'header_t []. However, when I look at the source code, header_t is defined just before packet_state_t, where packet_state_t references header_t. Thus, there shouldn't be any forward reference error, since header_t is clearly defined at the point at which it is referenced inside packet_state_t. The line in which the error occurs is marked with ERROR below. How to resolve?

```
 typedef struct header_t {
    uint8_t  hdr_id;         // header ID

    uint8_t  hdr_prefix;     // length of the prefix (preamble) before the header
    uint8_t  hdr_gap;        // length of the gap between header and payload
    uint16_t  hdr_flags;      // flags for this header
    uint16_t hdr_postfix;    // length of the postfix (trailer) after the payload
    uint32_t hdr_offset;     // offset into the packet_t->data buffer
    uint32_t hdr_length;     // length of the header in packet_t->data buffer
    uint32_t hdr_payload;    // length of the payload

    uint8_t   hdr_subcount;  // number of sub-headers
    header_t  *hdr_subheader;   // Index of the first subheader in packet_t

    jobject  hdr_analysis;   // Java JAnalysis based object if not null
} header_t;

typedef struct packet_state_t {
    flow_key_t pkt_flow_key; // Flow key calculated for this packet, must be first
    uint8_t pkt_flags;       // flags for this packet
    jobject pkt_analysis;    // Java JAnalysis based object if not null
    uint64_t pkt_frame_num;  // Packet's frame number assigned by scanner
    uint64_t pkt_header_map; // bit map of presence of headers

    uint32_t pkt_wirelen;    // Original packet size
    uint32_t pkt_buflen;     // Captured length

    int8_t pkt_header_count; // total number of main headers found
    header_t pkt_headers[];  // One per header + 1 more for payload ERROR HERE!!!

    int8_t pkt_subheader_count;  // total number of sub headers found
    header_t pkt_subheaders[];  // One per header + 1 more for payload
} packet_state_t;
```

Comment: I don't think it is legal to have an empty array field (`header_t pkt_headers[]`) that is not at the end of a struct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type `header_t` is just fine, but the compiler is *actually* complaining about the type `header_t[]`, i.e. "array of indeterminate length of `header_t`", which has an incomplete type because the compiler doesn't know how big it is (it couldn't possibly).

C99 (but not C89) supports what's called a *flexible array member* in structures, which is exactly this, but *only* at the end of a structure:

```
struct X {
  // any member declarations
  ...
  AnyType lastMemberArray[];  // This must be the LAST member
};
```

This is allowed, but it makes the structure you declared also an incomplete type because again, the compiler doesn't know how big it is.  The only way to use it is to dynamically allocate memory of the required size or to cast an already allocated block of memory.  For example:

```
// Allocate an X instance with space for 3 members in lastMemberArray:
X *x = malloc(sizeof(X) + 3 * sizeof(AnyType));
// Can now use x->lastMemberArray[0] through x->lastMemberArray[2]
...

// Alternatively:
char buffer[sizeof(X) + 3 * sizeof(AnyType)];
X *x = (X *)buffer;
// Same as above
```

Why does the flexible array member have to come last in the struct?  Imagine if other members came after it.  How could the compiler generate code to access those members?

```
// If this were allowed:
struct X {
  AnyType flexibleArray[];
  int memberAfter;
};

void doSomething(X *x) {
  // How does the compiler generate code for this?  It doesn't know what offset
  // memberAfter is from the start of the object, because the array doesn't
  // have a known size
  printf("memberAfter = %d\n", x->memberAfter);
}
```

Hence, you can't have a structure with more than one flexible array member, because then clearly one of them wouldn't be the last structure member, so your definition is not allowed.

Whatever library code you're writing, it couldn't have used two flexible array members to begin with, or it wouldn't have compiled on any platform.  I suggest you investigate the original code to find out what it did; if it's using standard ISO C features without relying on any platform-specific or implementation-specific behavior or extensions, you should have no trouble porting it.

Without being able to see the original code, I'd recommend you switch from using an inline flexible array member to a dynamically allocated array with a pointer, at least for the first array (and probably also the second for consistency):

```
typedef struct packet_state_t {
    flow_key_t pkt_flow_key; // Flow key calculated for this packet, must be first
    uint8_t pkt_flags;       // flags for this packet
    jobject pkt_analysis;    // Java JAnalysis based object if not null
    uint64_t pkt_frame_num;  // Packet's frame number assigned by scanner
    uint64_t pkt_header_map; // bit map of presence of headers

    uint32_t pkt_wirelen;    // Original packet size
    uint32_t pkt_buflen;     // Captured length

    int8_t pkt_header_count; // total number of main headers found
    header_t *pkt_headers;   // POINTER here, not an array

    int8_t pkt_subheader_count;  // total number of sub headers found
    header_t *pkt_subheaders;    // POINTER here, not an array
} packet_state_t;
```

---

**EDIT**

I downloaded the jnetpcap code and compiled it on Linux to see what happened.  To my surprise, it compiled.  The compiler command invoked was:

```
gcc -c -fPIC -DLIBPCAP_VERSION=0x1532 -I/tmp/jnetpcap/build/include -I/tmp/jnetpcap/src/c -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/jnetpcap.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/packet_flow.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/packet_jheader.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/jnetpcap_pcap_header.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/nio_jbuffer.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/winpcap_stat_ex.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/winpcap_send_queue.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/winpcap_ext.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/util_debug.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/util_crc16.c /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/jnetpcap_ids.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/jnetpcap_dumper.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/jnetpcap_utils.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/util_in_cksum.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/jnetpcap_beta.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/nio_jmemory.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/util_crc32.c /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/packet_jsmall_scanner.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/mac_addr_sys.c /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/packet_protocol.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/nio_jnumber.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/packet_jheader_scanner.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/library.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/packet_jscan.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/jnetpcap_pcap100.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/mac_addr_dlpi.c /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/util_checksum.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/packet_jpacket.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/winpcap_ids.cpp /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/jnetpcap_bpf.cpp
```

So the first thing that's going on here is that this is C++, not C.  C++ does not support flexible array members at all, although some compilers support them as extensions.  C++03 §9.2/8 says:

> [...] When an array is used as the type of a nonstatic member all dimensions shall be specified.

And C++11 §9.2/9 says:

> 9 Non-static (9.4) data members shall not have incomplete types. [...]

When I compile this code in g++ 4.8.2 with a higher warning level (`-Wall -Wextra pedantic`), it warns as follows:

```
In file included from /tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/packet_jscan.cpp:28:0:
/tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/packet_jscanner.h:287:23: warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array ‘pkt_headers’ [-Wpedantic]
  header_t pkt_headers[];  // One per header + 1 more for payload
                       ^
/tmp/jnetpcap/src/c/packet_jscanner.h:290:26: warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array ‘pkt_subheaders’ [-Wpedantic]
  header_t pkt_subheaders[];  // One per header + 1 more for payload
```

So what g++ is doing (contrary to the C++ standard) is converting the arrays of unspecified size to arrays of size 0.  The first one (`pkt_headers`) works exactly like the flexible array member in C99, in that if you've allocated the proper amount of memory, you can access the array members of that normally up to the maximum size.  But if you ever access any members *after* that (particularly `pkt_subheader_count` and `pkt_subheaders`), the compiler generates code as if `pkt_headers` had size 0, i.e. if the struct were equivalent to this:

```
typedef struct packet_state_t {
    flow_key_t pkt_flow_key; // Flow key calculated for this packet, must be first
    uint8_t pkt_flags;       // flags for this packet
    jobject pkt_analysis;    // Java JAnalysis based object if not null
    uint64_t pkt_frame_num;  // Packet's frame number assigned by scanner
    uint64_t pkt_header_map; // bit map of presence of headers

    uint32_t pkt_wirelen;    // Original packet size
    uint32_t pkt_buflen;     // Captured length

    int8_t pkt_header_count; // total number of main headers found
    // NOTHING HERE (array of size 0)

    int8_t pkt_subheader_count;  // total number of sub headers found
    header_t pkt_subheaders[];  // One per header + 1 more for payload
} packet_state_t;
```

Which would cause accesses to `pkt_subheader_count` (and probably also access to `pkt_subheaders`) to access the exact same memory as as `pkt_headers[0]`.

Why does the happen to work out ok?  **Because the code in this project never accesses `pkt_subheader_count` or `pkt_subheaders` anywhere.**  If it did, the code wouldn't work for the reasons described above unless it got extraordinarily lucky.  And it's not valid C++, it just happens to be accepted by the compiler.

Solution?  Just remove `pkt_subheader_count` and `pkt_subheaders` from the structure declaration.  They're not used anywhere in code, and removing them allows `pkt_headers[]` to be the last member of the structure, so it's a valid flexible array member, which is valid C99 or a non-standard compiler extension in C++.

Comment: Adam.. Thanks for the contribution. However, this code apparently compiles fine on Linux. It doesn't compile on Mac OS X. Isn't there a compiler switch or something to make this work? If I make the code changes you propose, will it affect other parts of the program. I want to try to avoid rewriting large sections of code if possible.

Comment: Switching to a pointer seemed to have gotten rid of that error.

Comment: @jamie: It shouldn't be able to compile at all on Linux.  Can you provide an example, along with the exact compiler version and compiler options used?

Comment: I'm trying to compile the 1.4 trunk of Jnetpcap http://jnetpcap.com/?q=sources. The problem also occurs on 1.3.1 of Jnetpcap. Linux and Windows are both supported OS'es, not Mac OS X.

Comment: That's fascinating, because there's no way that should compile at all.  Do you know what compiler, compiler version, and compiler options are being used to compile that?  Is that code compiled at all?  C99 is very clear about this in §6.7.2.1/2.

Comment: Adam.. after making your change, I was able to compile the library on MacOX. The problem is that I get a core dump when I attempt to use the library in Java. I am not sure if it related to your patch.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the comprehensive analysis. That is excellent. Its very clear now. I will try your suggestion and see if the program behaves itself.

Answer (score 0):

In definition of `struct header_t`

Change

```
header_t  *hdr_subheader;   // Index of the first subheader in packet_t
```

to

```
struct header_t  *hdr_subheader;   // Index of the first subheader in packet_t
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, however not where the error is. The error is in typedef struct packet_state_t { ...  header_t pkt_headers[]; }.. In any case, I tried your suggestion, it made no difference.

Comment: This shouldn't matter. The typedef and the struct tag reside in different scopes.